# npm install angular-cli not working

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I have installed Latest nodeJS(v.8.9.1) and npm(6.1.0), though im getting below problem

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'F:\AngularProject\Node\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this 
file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'F:\AngularProject\Node\package.json'
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is 
installed. You must install peer
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN Node No description
npm WARN Node No repository field.
npm WARN Node No README data
npm WARN Node No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darw
in","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3
added 922 packages from 761 contributors and audited 5006 packages in 
280.149s
found 14 vulnerabilities (1 low, 9 moderate, 4 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I have searched in net,but couldn't sort out.I tried the some possible ways like clear npm cache,installed latest npm,Tried in administrator console. But still unable to find out.

Comment: Start console with admin rights and try again. Second thing - did you tried go inside this folder and run ng serve?

Comment: Looks like it's working to me, most of those warnings you can ignore. It's odd that its warning you about rxjs though, installing @angular/cli@latest should automatically pull and install the needed version of rxjs. (nvm just saw that you are using angular ver 2)

Comment: I tried in administrator console also and i tried to create a new folder by `ng new sample`, it throws `ng is not recognized as internal or external command`

Comment: if i ignore this warning, it throws `ng is not recognized as internal or external command` while i create new folder using `ngcommand` @diopside

Comment: Sounds like its not properly modifying your PATH environment variable in Windows. Whenever I do 'npm install --global @angular/cli@latest' on windows it usually is good about automatically adding the needed directories to my PATH envir. variable (if its done w/ administrator rights).  Is there any reason you don't want to use the latest angular?

Comment: omg.. `npm install --g @angular/cli@latest` is working for me. How this happens. There is no reason for me to use latest angular. @diopside